# save/convert pyplot figure to BLOB url

Tags: matplotlib, geopandas

I am generating a plot from some postgis data using geopandas like this

```
db_connection_url = "postgresql://urser:pw@dburl:25060/dbname";
con = create_engine(db_connection_url)  
sql = 'SELECT geom FROM mytable where var > 0.5' 
df = geopandas.GeoDataFrame.from_postgis(sql, con)
```

I can easily save this plot as a jpg like this

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df.plot()
plt.savefig('world.jpg')
```

The catch is I am running this on a server and would like to return the result as a blob url instead of a jpg file. I'd like to do this in python without having to savefig to the local file system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a demo code that shows how to get the image from a plot as a `base64` code.

```
from io import BytesIO, StringIO
import base64
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import LineString
#import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create a dataframe from CSV data
df5 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(
"""id longitude latitude
828  4.8906  52.3723
630  4.8892  52.3694
234  4.8863  52.3671"""), sep="\s+")

# Create a LineString from all points in `df5` dataframe
ls = LineString( df5[['longitude','latitude']].to_numpy() )
line_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame( [['1021']],crs='epsg:4326', geometry=[ls] )

fig = plt.figure(figsize=[6,7])
ax = fig.gca()

# Plot the data from `line_gdf` geodataframe
line_gdf.plot(color="red", ax=ax);
df5.plot("longitude", "latitude", kind="scatter", ax=ax);

# Get the (plotted) image into memory file
imgdata = BytesIO()
fig.savefig(imgdata, dpi=60, format='png')
imgdata.seek(0)  #rewind the data
imgJpg = imgdata.getvalue()

html = """<html><body><img src="data:image/png;base64,{}"/></body></html>""".format(base64.encodebytes(imgdata.getvalue()).decode())

plt.show()
```

You get the `base64` image embedded in HTML code (in `html` variable). In Jupyter notebook, you can display the obtained HTML code as follows.

```
from IPython.display import HTML
HTML(html)
```

[image: html_output]

The output data of the image you may need:

```
(1) Binary: just get it from the content of `imgJpg` (smaller size)
(2) `base64` data string, which can be obtained from:
```

```
base64.encodebytes(imgdata.getvalue()).decode()
```

Warning, it will be a very long string in general.